# Linked files illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Hi can anyone advise about linked files. How do you stop it getting lost. Is it like indesign where you have a links folder?

For logos should you just copy and paste in so it's embedded?

Many thanks

Comment: You should use a document management system. But no you can not be 100% safe in either indesign nor illustrator.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1: When saving the .AI file, tick "Include Linked Files"
 - This embeds all linked files into the .AI

2: Keep everything in the same place, i.e. in a work folder for that project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's an expected "Links" folder - when this folder is present in the same directory as your .ai file and through some turn of events any placed files become 'lost', it will first search the Links folder for those files.