# How to deal with lost pdf figure in eps file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, eps

I am making a figure which includes several subfigures with adobe illustrator. Some of the subfigures are copied & pasted from .pdf files, which include a figrue, respectively. However, after saving the combined figure and closing AI, sometimes when I reopen the figure, AI prompts "can't find the linked figure...", then if click on "ignore" the pdf subfigures will be lost in the opened figure.

What I am doing wrong? Can anybody please suggest how to resolve the issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: That error means there are missing linked files.  For some reason, the links in Illustrator are no longer pointing to the linked file. See the answer given by Digital Lightcraft in this [related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100909/linked-files-illustrator)

Comment: @BillyKerr thank you for the link :)

Comment: Linked resources are usually problematic to people when they first encounter the concept. Its extremely useful stuff but if you dont realize that data is externally linked you get into trouble fast and usually its this trouble that makes you realize the thing exists. Illustrator files dont usually include raster data, because illustrator does not edit them.

Comment: @joojaa thanks for the information. Are all figures in .pdf files raster data?

Comment: @Enter no depends on the pdf.